# Only getY() returns 0 in a TableLayout

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I'm using `tablelayout` to display a board. My problem is with `getY()`, always return `0.0`, but `getX()` always return a valid value. I've tried to change some values in my view but is not working.  The view that returns `0.0` is with id: `b0x0`.

Any idea?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b0x0"
                android:tag="0x0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:text="@string/value"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:gravity="center" />
...
```

**Edit**

My `getY()` is called when someone pressed a box in the board. I want to use `getX()` and `getY()` to display a keypad.

The caller of my board:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        iniBoard();
    ...
}

// initialize and set all the board's textviews
private void iniBoard() {
     for (int i = 0; i < mBoardIds.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < mBoardIds.length; j++) {
              mBoardTextView[i][j].setOnClickListener(mBoardListener);
        }
    }
}
```

The listener for my board:

```
private View.OnClickListener mBoardListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        coord = getBoxCoordinates(v);
        ...
}};

// get the coordinates where should appear my keypad
private float[] getBoxCoordinates(View v) {

     String[] str;
     float x, y, coord[];

     ...
     Log.d(TAG, "getX: " + v.getX() + " getY: " + v.getY());
     Log.d(TAG, "height: " + v.getHeight() + " width: " + v.getWidth());
     Log.d(TAG, "X: " + v.getX() + " Y: " + v.getY());
     Log.d(TAG, "windows width: " + mBoardView.getWidth());
     ...
 }
```

Comment: are you asking for these values after the view is drawn?

Comment: The question is not clear. Give more details and copy snippet of your Java code

Comment: @BojanKseneman, I'm calling it from my `onActivityCreated`. I'm using fragments.